# Jena library is not writing output to an external RDF/XML file

Tags: java, file-io, jena

I am having an issue with my jena library's writing method.
I have following piece of code which is supposed to write the output in external file but it is not doing so.

```
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom;


public class Tutorial04 extends Object {

// some definitions
static String tutorialURI  = "http://hostname/rdf/tutorial/";
static String briansName   = "Brian McBride";
static String briansEmail1 = "brian_mcbride@hp.com";
static String briansEmail2 = "brian_mcbride@hpl.hp.com";
static String title        = "An Introduction to RDF and the Jena API";
static String date         = "23/01/2001";

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main (String args[]) {

    // some definitions
    String personURI    = "http://somewhere/JohnSmith";
    String givenName    = "John";
    String familyName   = "Smith";
    String fullName     = givenName + " " + familyName;
    // create an empty model
    Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

    // create the resource
    //   and add the properties cascading style
    Resource johnSmith
      = model.createResource(personURI)
             .addProperty(VCARD.FN, fullName)
             .addProperty(VCARD.N,
                          model.createResource()
                               .addProperty(VCARD.Given, givenName)
                               .addProperty(VCARD.Family, familyName));

    // now write the model in XML form to a file
  //  model.write(System.out, "RDF/XML");
    model.write(System.out,"RDF/XML");
}
```

}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have:

```
model.write(System.out,"RDF/XML");
```

which says *"please write the contents of this model to standard output"* i.e. not to any named file. To write the model to a file, you'll need to say which file:

```
String fileName = "your_file_name_here.rdf";
FileWriter out = new FileWriter( fileName );
try {
    model.write( out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV" );
}
finally {
   try {
       out.close();
   }
   catch (IOException closeException) {
       // ignore
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ian :) it helped.
Also I will need your some more help in my final year project. Do you also have know-how of Jena Library?

Comment: Glad it was helpful. If you need other assistance on Jena, you can continue to ask questions here or post a message to the Jenu user group: see http://jena.apache.org/help_and_support/index.html

Comment: Hi Ian. Can I have your email address please?
I will be needing assistance on some task in jena this week

Comment: Hi Faisal, the best place to email Jena questions is the Jena users list that I mentioned in my last comment. You get a whole community of people helping you then, not just one. Plus, your questions and the answers they get may help other people.