# RDF dataset : write a DataSource into a file

Tags: java, rdf, jena

i want to write the results that i have in my datasource into a file. i have created a default graph, then i add to it some named graphs. the code that i already have is the following :

```
                DataSource  datasource = DatasetFactory.create() ;
                Model model1 = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
                datasource.setDefaultModel(model1);
                Resource subject = model1.createResource(g);
                Property predicateSource = model1.createProperty(prefix.concat(hassource));
                Property predicateProbability = model1.createProperty(prefix.concat(hasprobability));
                Resource objectSource = model1.createResource(source);      
                Resource objectProbability = model1.createResource(probability); 
                model1.add(subject, predicateSource, objectSource);
                model1.add(subject, predicateProbability, objectProbability);
                this.translator.stringToRDF(lineRDF,lineSplit);
                datasource.addNamedModel(g, this.translator.getModel()) ;
```

Comment: So you want to write the `DataSource`? The results? Please clarify.

Comment: My dataSource contains a default model and a named model that's what i want to write in the file

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-output.html) documentation:

```
FileWriter out = new FileWriter( fileName );
try {
   RDFDataMgr.write(out, model1, "TURTLE") ;
}
finally {
  try {
     out.close();
  }
  catch (IOException closeException) {
  }
}
```

You can also use `model.write()` as shown in [Jena library is not writing output to an external RDF/XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16766408/jena-library-is-not-writing-output-to-an-external-rdf-xml-file).

Comment: but this only write the default model, i actually want to write in a file the DataSource that contains the default and named model

Answer (score 1):

DataSource is no longer in the codebase. You are running an old version of Jena.

It was a subclass of Dataset.  You can write a dataset with RDFDataMgr (if that exists in the version you are running).

Upgrading would be a good idea.